# Once menu item is clicked, close menu and revert the classnames & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok... So I have this drop down menu working as I'd like... however I'm trying to figure out how to revert the function back to it's original state after a menu item is clicked.

So first when you trigger the function it does & works great the following:
It swaps out .menu_hide and .lockscreen for .menu_show and .lockscreen_on.

```
// show and hide mobile menu
$('#triggerMobileMenu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Toggle all 4 classes off or on
    $('#mobileMenu').toggleClass('menu_hide menu_show');
    $('#mobileScreen').toggleClass('lockscreen_off lockscreen_on');
```

But now I'm trying to add another piece that says once a menu item is clicked, close the menu and swap the classes back to their original state from .menu_show and .lockscreen_on, to .menu_hide and .lockscreen_off.

```
    $('#mobileMenu ul li a').on('click',function(){
        $('#mobileMenu').toggleClass('menu_show menu_hide')({ autoCloseOnClick: true });
        $('#mobileScreen').toggleClass('lockscreen_on lockscreen_off')({ autoCloseOnClick: true });
    });
});
```

I should also note that on the same page a scroll to id# may be happening vs just simply taking you to the new url/page. Either case will happen though.

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle

Comment: Are the attributes of the `_on` and `_show` classes always there (default?) If so why not just attach those to the ID, then only toggle the `_hide` and `_off` classes.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyborg/fq8e3/]

Comment: I added a comment in JS Fiddle to the site where the live working page sits. The mobile menu select icon that triggers the drop menu is in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're making this too complicated. Use the same event handler for both a#triggerMobileMenu and ul#mobileMenu li a since you're having them do the same thing (toggle the visibility of the menu and another element).

```
$('a#triggerMobileMenu, ul#mobileMenu li a').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#mobileMenu').toggleClass('menu_hide menu_show');
    $('#mobileScreen').toggleClass('lockscreen_off lockscreen_on');
});
```

If you need to know which element was clicked in the event handler, evt.target is available:

```
if( $(evt.target).is($('a#triggerMobileMenu')) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Mph6t/3/

Comment: Works like a champ! Thanks for helping me make it better and more concise!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working as intended.  I had to fix some id names that may have been switched in the translation to jsfiddle.  [Here's a working one](http://jsfiddle.net/fq8e3/11/) as far as I can tell.  This leaves the `somename2` div still showing.  I assume that is going to be blank and just for locking the screen right?

I also changed the link to a new tab for testing purposes.  FYI.

Relevant changes are:

```
$('#somename1 ul li a').on('click',function(){
    $('#somename1').toggleClass('menu_show menu_hide')({ autoCloseOnClick: true });
    $('#somename2').toggleClass('lockscreen_on lockscreen_off')({ autoCloseOnClick: true });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I see at least one problem.  You are calling `autoCloseOnClick: true` which Chrome is reporting as a function.  But you don't have it defined anywhere.  Get rid of that and see if that works.

Comment: Josh Thanks! That helps me fully understand better. Thanks for the efforts!